# Why when i log-in using another desktop environment, apps doesn't appear to be installed?

Tags: 14.04, unity, gnome, desktop-environments, appmenu

I want change Unity desktop since is too slow and replace it with another one, GNOME or Budgie Desktop. Then i downloaded Gnome. I restart the PC and i log-in with gnome. But when i go to the "app drawer" or "Gnome Dash", Appear a text saying "No apps found". So i install Budgie Desktop, but the same problem occurs!. Recommendations about different desktops are also welcome. Thanks.

*Using Ubuntu 14.04 LTS Spanish, 64 bits.*

Comment: Do you apps show n `/usr/share/applications`? Also, how did you install Gnome?

Comment: @wilf Yeah the apps are in /usr/share/applications. I  installed GNOME in Ubuntu Software Center.